# Parse Arabic XML in Android

Tags: android, parsing, xml-parsing, arabic

I need to parse an XML. The problem is that the XML is in Arabic.

eg:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <شهر>1</شهر>
  <فصل>20111</فصل>
  <سكن>0</سكن>
  <سلفة>0</سلفة>
  <محمول>0</محمول>
  <آيفون4>0</آيفون4>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <شهر>10</شهر>
  <فصل>20111</فصل>
  <سكن>0</سكن>
  <سلفة>0</سلفة>
  <محمول>0</محمول>
  <آيفون4>0</آيفون4>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <شهر>11</شهر>
  <فصل>20111</فصل>
  <سكن>0</سكن>
  <سلفة>0</سلفة>
  <محمول>0</محمول>
  <آيفون4>0</آيفون4>
 </ROW>
 <ROW>
  <شهر>12</شهر>
  <فصل>20111</فصل>
  <سكن>0</سكن>
  <سلفة>0</سلفة>
  <محمول>0</محمول>
  <آيفون4>0</آيفون4>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Add to it, the end tags comes first and then the start tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is in encoding 
try to add:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
```

at the beginning of your document